# ARCore Image Extraction from GPU

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, arcore

I try to extract image directly from the GPU (so without using `AcquireCameraImageBytes()`) for performance reason (Samsung S9 can't reach 10fps) and to support the Xiaomi Pocophone I bought. I use the class TextureReader, included inside the ComputerVision example, but `OnImageAvailableCallback` is never called and log show some error during initialization:

> camera_utility: Failed to create OpenGL frame buffer.
>
> camera_utility: Failed to create OpenGL frame buffer.

I insert a couple of breakpoints inside **libarcore_camera_utility.so**. And I see that `glCheckFramebufferStatus` inside `TextureReader::create` **return 0** (so a error occurred), but `glGetError()` don't return any error. How it's possible resolve the problem?